# Android / Phone Gap - how to record MP3

Tags: cordova, audio

I'm trying to build a recorder which does not produce AMR files, but rather MP3 files from the Cordova PhoneGap.

media.startRecord produces AMR files.

Any idea?
or alternative ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On Android it does record in `.amr` format, on iOS it's in `.wav`, as it's explained [in the documentation](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.media). The only know plugin is [this one](https://github.com/keenan/cordova-phonegap-audio-encode) but it's only for iOS, in M4V and surely outdated. So you have only 2 choices :

1. Develop your own plugin (inspired by the cordova-phonegap-audio-encode one)
2. Send it to your sever where it will be quite easier to convert it.